# Asynchronous programming in c# before 5.0 without async & await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In my recent interview i was asked how we can achieve asynchronous programming in c# previous to 5.0 versions. I answered that by using a delegate's `BeginInvoke()` & `EndInvoke()` methods we can call a method asynchronously. But the interviewer seems to be not happy. SO, when i googled about it someone said it was Asynchronous Operation but not Asynchronous methods. Can someone explain how we cam write Asynchronous methods prior to C# 5.0 versions.

Comment: [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) could be an option.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @S.Akbari thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @roryap thanks for the reply.

Comment: Task parallel library can be used from C# 4 / .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

There are several historical approaches to asynchronous programming.

As far as the BCL goes, most instances follow either the [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx) (with APM being far more common). EAP generally uses `SynchronizationContext` under the covers to automatically resume on a "context". APM does not attempt to resume on a "context".

Before the EAP, there was another older pattern, seldom used because it turned out to be somewhat too tightly integrated with WinForms and the whole `Component` system. AFAIK, this pattern does not have a name, but it is identifiable by a `SynchronizationObject` property which you can set to an instance of `ISynchronizeInvoke` (usually a WinForms control). The component then raises its events in the context of that `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance. Examples of this pattern in the BCL are rare, but there are a few: `System.Timers.Timer`, `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`, and `System.Diagnostics.Process` come to mind.

It's also possible to say that any kind of event-based system is asynchronous. Even if it doesn't follow EAP or the `ISynchronizeInvoke` pattern, any object that can raise events in the future to notify subscribers can be considered an asynchronous component.

You can consider Rx (Reactive Extensions) as a superset of asynchronous programming. Rx is literally "events done right", and as such it can also be used to implement asynchronous components.

Finally, there are old-fashioned callbacks (i.e., Continuation Passing Style - CPS). This became somewhat common in at least one OSS library many years ago, due to the complexities of correctly implementing APM or EAP. The official Node.js asynchronous pattern is CPS, though they're quickly moving towards `async`/`await` now (official APIs are still CPS, which are wrapped into `await`-compatible promises). Anyway, there was one .NET OSS library in particular many years ago that was fairly common and used CPS. My Google-Fu is failing me, but it might have been an early HTTP client?

The following are *not* examples of asynchronous programming:

- `Task.Factory.StartNew`
- `new Task`
- `Delegate.BeginInvoke`
- `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`
- `new Thread`
- `Task[Ex].Run`

All of the above just schedule code to run somewhere, whether on the thread pool thread or not, and thus are not truly asynchronous. This is in spite of the rather confusing term in the MSDN documentation "[asynchronous delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb(v=vs.110).aspx)" when describing `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, which only describes *fake* asynchrony, not true asynchrony (and is likely the cause of your interview confusion).

Fake asynchrony is where one thread acts treats the operation *as if* it were asynchronous, but in reality the operation is just synchronous *on a different thread*. For more about true asynchrony and why it doesn't require threads, see my blog post [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: Given `Task` in .NET 4, I outlined a way to do TAP without async/await in C# 5. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504197/Await-Tasks-in-Csharp4-using-Iterators It does have some limitations which are given in the article.

Answer (score 2):

Since C#.NET version 4.0 there is the class [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) inside the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) (Task Parallel Library). Tasks are 'Futures' or also known as 'Promises'.

You can use them as follows:

```
Task<int> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  //Long Operation
);
  //perform other work
int result = task.Result;
```

...where

- `task` represents the asynchronous call
- `task.Result` is the access to its result; similar as done with futures

As known from [Java's CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), the TPL provides [Task Continuations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx), where you define a task, which you want to start after the first task finished.

You can use them as follows:

```
task1.
      ContinueWith(task2).
          ContinueWith(task3);
```

OR even with Multi Continuation like this:

```
Task.Factory.
    ContinueWhenAll(taskArray, continuation);
```

or

```
Task.Factory.
    ContinueWhenAny(taskArray, continuation);
```

I hope this helps your understanding.